# Stop some operation when response is received from the server

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a form after filling in which I submit it to the backend. If the form is valid, I have to show pop up with checkboxes. Checkboxes should start to be checked, in case if the response from the server came 1700, all checkboxes must be checked and pop up must be closed, and if the response is not 1700 there should be a couple of checkboxes checked, but not all, pop up should be closed and should be redirect to another page. I can only make a limited number of checked checkboxes (when the response is not 1700). But how to make it different each time? So that as soon as the response comes from the server and it is not 1700, immediately stop checking.

```
public sendApplication(): void {
    if (this.formService.isFormValid(this.formGroup)) {
        this.dialogProcessing
            = this.dialog.open(FoDialogBankVerificationComponent, {
            width: '500px',
            disableClose: true,
            data: this.checkBoxValues,
        });
        this.submit()
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                timeout(10000))
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.checkBoxValues.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
                        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                            checkbox.isChecked = true;
                            if (res.id === 1700) {
                                if (index === this.checkBoxValues.length - 1) {
                                    this.status = res.id;
                                    this.dialogProcessing.close();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (index === 3) {
                                    this.dialogProcessing.close();
                                    this.navigationService.navigateToDeniedPage();
                                }
                            }
                            clearInterval(this.interval);
                        }, index * 1000);
                    });
                },
                () => {
                    this.dialogProcessing.close();
                    this.notificationService.showGetErrorNotification();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you faced any error ?

Comment: no, only if i log index of forEach function, it's executed again and again even when redirect was to another page

Comment: what is the interval for? I thought you call a normal http server and it only returns the value once...